# Yup - comma decimal separator instead of dot

Tags: javascript, validation, formik, yup

I'm using a simple [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) schema like this to validate a Formik input field in React Native:

```js
Yup.number().positive()
```

My users are going to use the comma separator for decimals, so I need the schema to throw an error for values such as `1.35` and accept values like `1,35`. Using a regex seems off the table as the `matches` method is only available for strings.

Comment: Convert it to string and use regex...

Comment: Is there a way to keep the `number` type? Because I'll need to concatenate some extra "number" validations later on.

Comment: After the regex check you can split by "," and use parseInt to ceonvert them as integer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After tinkering a bit with `transform`, this what ended up working for me:

```js
Yup.number()
   .transform((_, value) => {
      if (value.includes('.')) {
        return null;
      }
      return +value.replace(/,/, '.');
    })
    .positive(),
```

Comment: It is a bit sad that there is no out of the box localisation handling in yup.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a function in Yup to be able to parse number in different formats. But one easy way is to transform/replace the comma by nothing so it become a number

```js
number().transform((o, v) => parseInt(v.replace(/,/g, '')))
```

This way your number `10,000` become `10000` and is indeed a valid number.

On the other hand `10.000` stay `10.000` and is not valid.

Comment: `10,000` should be equal to `10`, not `10000`. The `transform` method seems to be a decent workaround though, I'll work on that.

Comment: oups my bad when writing this answer I was carried away with number format and did not check the decimal part. Should work the same for decimal